# How to change session_save_path magento 1

Tags: magento, localhost, memcached

I'm new in magento and i got invalid form key issue on login.
I move my live site to localhost.
I found my sessions path are set as my live site have and I want to set them according to my localhost.
My current session tags are

```
    <session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>
    <session_save_path><![CDATA[unix:///var/tmp/memcached.example.example.com_sessions.sock?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path>
```

How can I set them for my localhost to resolve following Issue  ?

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?